# How to move browser tabs to different monitors using a script?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, macros, sikuli

[image]I have a 3 monitor setup which is connected to a PC. It displays a Google Chrome tab on each of the screens with some dashboard. It will auto log off every night from the website (I cannot control that). So I need to manually login to it, open the tabs, then move it to each of the monitors every night. I am trying to automate this task. I am trying to use [Sikuli slides](http://www.sikuli.org/) to do it. Right now  I am able to login, open tabs, and click on buttons. But I am not able to drag the tabs to other monitors. It doesn't matter which tab is displayed in which monitor. The PC is running Windows 7. How can I get it done ? Any scripting language or tool which is available in windows is fine. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Added an image which describes my need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did to fix it:

Used [MouseRecorder](http://mouserecorder.com/) to record the mouse movements and keystrokes including my username and password. Using this, I logged in, opened tabs, clicked on buttons and moved them to different monitors.

Problem with this is that it is not possible to load a saved macro and run using the commandline (or I could not figure out). So I used [Mouse Controller](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mousecontroller/) to record the mouse movement to open MouseRecorder and click on run. [It cannot record key strokes]. Mouse controller has option to run from commandline with ability to accept the filename as argument.

I wrote a batch file to open and run MouseRecorder and scheduled to run every night using task scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

You're opening the same thing on the same computer on the same screens, so it will be in the same place every time.

AutoHotKey (AHK) can do click-and-drag from a start coordinate to an end coordinate:

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseClickDrag.htm

Run AutoHotKey, right click on the icon in the taskbar notification area (systray) and click 'Window Spy', and it will bring up AHK's helper tool. Now you can click on the Chrome tabs and look in AHK to see the coordinates of the mouse pointer, so you can plug those into the command. And drag/drop the browser and look at the mouse coordinates there, too.

(And if you weren't using Windows 7, but instead 8 or 8.1 or 10, you could use Aero Snap with Win+RightArrow, Win+RightArrow and Win+UpArrow to move the active window to the edge of the center screen, then to the right screen, then to fullscreen it).

(Or you could use Alt-Space, M, Arrow Keys to script moving the focused window around).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I managed to get it done in another way. Answer added